# Cloudera Manager installer fails on Ubuntu

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-manager

I am trying to install cloudera-manager-installer.bin, and I encounter the error:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package oracle-j2sdk1.6
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'oracle-j2sdk1.6'
```

I am running Java 7 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.  One [post](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/scm-users/40bRUKjlGFc) suggests that it could be because the Ubuntu environment is messed up, but it does not give direction on how to correct the environment.

How do I correct this and install cloudera manager?

Comment: another [post](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/scm-users/egmTNqRdH50/BG8QdOjO4FsJ) suggests to install cloudera manager manually and I am following that as of now. Currently, I am not getting above error but a different one which I am researching.